# Qual o nome e diferenças entre as seguintes formas de se trabalhar com objetos em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Escrevi o mesmo código de diversas formas, porém não sei como descrever cada uma delas, seu nome correto e diferenças.

Os códigos são os seguintes:

```js
// Código 1

function Pessoa(nome)
{
    this.nome = nome;

    this.dizerNome = function()
    {
        alert(this.nome);
    }
}

var Pessoa1 = new Pessoa("Pedro");
Pessoa1.dizerNome();
```

```js
// Código 2
var Pessoa =
{
    nome: null,
 
    dizerNome: function()
    {
        alert(this.nome);
    }
}

var Pessoa1 = Object.create(Pessoa);
Pessoa1.nome = "Pedro";
Pessoa1.dizerNome();
```

```js
// Código 3
function Pessoa(nome)
{
    this.nome = nome;
};

Pessoa.prototype.dizerNome = function()
{
    alert(this.nome);
};

var Pessoa1 = new Pessoa("Pedro");

Pessoa1.dizerNome();
```

Qual o nome e diferença entre cada uma dessas formas de se trabalhar com objetos, e qual o mais utilizado no JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há duas maneiras de usar objetos em JavaScript: com o Object Literal usando pares de chave-valor ("key-value pairs"); ou usando uma função que será o construtor do objeto.

**Object Literal**: nesse modo de uso, você apenas define uma variável com braces {} e cada chave-valor separado por uma vírgula.

**Função**: defina uma função que será a base para instanciar novos objetos. Nesse caso, como está num bloco de uma função, você escreve statements de programação normalmente, usando ponto e vírgula no final de cada statement.

No seu exemplo, Código 1 se refere a usar uma função que define um blueprint (ou uma classe, embora que versões do JavaScript antes de ES6 não têm classes).

Em Código 2, você está usando o Object Literal. Mas noto que você usou Object.create, mas eu acho que não deve usá-lo dessa forma porquê o que acontece é que quando você passa Pessoa pra função [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), você cria um objeto cujo prototype é Pessoa. Quando você for mudar o nome, por exemplo, o nome será definido em Pessoa1, mas você ainda terá o nome no prototype. Pra fazer um experimento, rode o seu código no Web Console do Chrome Dev Tools (ou console de outro navegador) e verifique o valor da variável Pessoa1 em Código 2. Você verá que o objeto Pessoa1 tem uma propriedade nome com valor Pedro, mas também que tem a pseudo-propriedade `__proto__` com o objeto Pessoa como o prototype. E esse objeto também tem uma propriedade nome que é null! Então se você não estivesse definido o nome como Pedro, o JavaScript iria olhar no prototype pra ver se tem a propriedade nome (como tem, iria mostrar null, o seu valor).

Enfim, eu recomendo usar funções para criar um blueprint pro objeto (i.e. classe) e definir o prototype como o seu exemplo em **Codigo 3**. Isto é, se você estiver instanciando objetos de uma espécie de classe. O modo de fazer objetos usando objet literal também é válido, embora para outras ocasiões.

Aqui uma nota final sobre prototype: os atributos que forem únicos de cada objeto (for exemplo, nome, idade, altura, peso, etc), devem ser definidos dentro da função que define o blueprint pro objeto. O comportamento dos objetos, coisas que são comuns à todos eles (por exemplo: falar, andar, dormir, comer, beber, etc), devem ser definidos usando prototype. Quando você criar um objeto baseado em uma definição de função, aquele objeto terá suas próprias propriedades enquanto as funções definidas pelo prototype são comuns à todas as instâncias daquela função classe. Em outras palavras, tudo que é definido via o prototype só é definido uma vez enquanto os atributos da Pessoa são criados para cada instância.

Espero que tenha ajudado. Só um toque para todos que o ES6 em breve se tornará o padrão, então podem se acostumar a usar [classes em JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) usando a seguinte forma:

```
class Pessoa {
  constructor(nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
  }

  // Métodos protótipos
  dizerNome() {
    alert(this.nome);
  }
}
```

Comment: Foi muito esclarecedor, apenas uma dúvida em relação à sintax do ES6, eu pensei em utiliza-lo por se parecer mais com as linguagens que estou habituado, porém fiquei em dúvidas na questão de compatibilidade.

Comment: É verdade que a syntax do ES6 ainda não é suportada por todos, mas o que o pessoal faz é usar o BABEL (https://babeljs.io/) para converter a syntax para o ES5. Então você escreve em ES6, mas na realidade o BABEL converte tudo para a sintaxe de ES5, então vai funcionar tudo bem :)